# Lightest Linux distro for Node.js

Tags: linux, node.js, azure, virtual-machine

What is a good, ultra light Linux distro for Node.js.

No GUI, Just bash.

Planning to run Azure Extra Small VM instance.
Share CPU core, 768MB memory.

Comment: Literally any of them. It's almost entirely subjective. Not a suitable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not really related but I'd recommend this https://github.com/devert/vagrant-nodejs-app-starter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) [server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) is even light enough. Than you have a pretty easy / well-supported distribution. As added benefit you have distribution with LTS.

> Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS is a long-term support release, with support
>   guaranteed for five years from April 2012

Comment: Shall try it. Thanks. Is that a No GUI distro?

Comment: In the past the server edition used to be without GUI standard(but you could install one). I still believe this is valid now.